# Uncaught TypeError: $this.text is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The second statement in this code:

```
var $this = $(this).children('div.submenu1').children('a.subtile')[0],
title = $this.text(),
name = $this.attr('node').val;
```

produces this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $this.text is not a function
```

When I hover over `$this.text()` in Chrome debugger I can see the value I want to have in `title`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: $this is DOM object not, jquery object, either wrap it like $($this).text() ot $this.innerText to read text

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is happening because you're assigning to the variable `$this` a native DOM reference, not a jQuery reference. Only the latter has access to the jQuery API.

You're doing this by 'reaching inside' the array-like jQuery stack and extracting the native reference, via `[0]`. Lose this and it'll work:

```
var $this = $(this).children('div.submenu1').children('a.subtile'),
title = $this.text(), //<-- now has access to jQuery API
```

Answer (score 6):

`$this` is a DOM object, not a jQuery object. Either wrap it like `$($this).text()` or `$this.innerText` to read text.

Answer (score -2):

As this is was the first result, for me, when I Googled this, I will post my issue/solution. I had written Text() rather than text(). i.e My capitalisation was wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing this same issue, it ended up being that JavaScript was disabled on my browser. Make sure JavaScript is enabled to load on the page.