# Uncaught TypeError: this.text is not a function within on method but not outside it

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a div with two buttons and returns the ids of the wrapper and the buttons. When I use .text() to find the text of the button it works fine, but when i use .text() within the on method it gives me a TypeError.

```
         function generateTwoBtns(answerSpace, btnOneName, btnTwoName) {
                const btnHTML =
                    `
                        <div id="twoBtnWrapper">
                            <button id="btnOne">${btnOneName}</button>
                            <button id="btnTwo">${btnTwoName}</button>
                        </div>
                    `

                $(answerSpace).html(btnHTML)

                return {
                    wrapper: '#twoBtnWrapper',
                    btnOne: '#btnOne',
                    btnTwo: '#btnTwo'
                }
         }

        //Works
        console.log($(buttons.btnOne).text())

        //Doesn't work
        $(buttons.btnOne).on('click', function() {
                console.log(this.text())
            })
```

I've looked at the answer found here: [Uncaught TypeError: $this.text is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486107/uncaught-typeerror-this-text-is-not-a-function). This is the same sort of problem I'm having. but in my code i can't see why this.text() works fine outside the on method, but doesn't work within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` is a jQuery method, meant to be used on jQuery objects. In your event handler, `this` refers to a standard DOM element which does not have a `text` method, hence your error (`.text` is not a function that a DOM element has).

It works here:

```
console.log($(buttons.btnOne).text())
```

Because you are wrapping the DOM element(s) that match the `buttons.btnOne` selector in a jQuery object and then calling `.text()` on that.

Change the code to:

```
$(this).text()
```

So that the DOM "button" element that got clicked gets wrapped in a jQuery object and then it will work.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is because `this` actually refer to the DOM element, and the DOM element does not have a `.text()` method. What you want is to use it on a jQuery object, i.e.: `$(this)` instead:

```
$(buttons.btnOne).on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).text())
});
```

From the [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), they describe what `this` actually stands for in the context of a callback (emphasis my own):

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.) **To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be used with jQuery methods, use `$( this )`**.